# Android: Espresso, No views in hierarchy found matching

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I'm testing the launch of a fragment inside my activity, so after performing a click on button that going to launch the fragment, I tested the existing of a text on view inside the launched fragment, but the test fail even though that fragment is launched on my phone, and even in the View Hierarchy is showing that the text exist :

```
View Hierarchy:

+--------->AppCompatTextView{id=2131886318, res-name=text3_textView, visibility=VISIBLE, width=768, height=68, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=695.0, text=Pour finaliser votre inscription nous avons besion
d'une photo de profil, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
```

The test fail here :

```
onView(withText("photo de profil")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

I'm wondering why espresso fail this test, is it because it doesn't wait for the launch of the fragment?

Btw I turned animations off.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The espresso withText method match that all the string is equal.

In your case you need to match if the string ends with your string.

Your code should be this:

```
onView(withText(endsWith("photo de profil"))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Here you have more examples: http://qathread.blogspot.com.br/2014/01/discovering-espresso-for-android.html

Comment: Man, thanks a ton, I can't believe I wasted a whole day on that.

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb its for this things that we have stack overflow, everyone feels this too, I am happy to help :D

Comment: this is a temporary patch, if screen contains duplicate text at number of places then it wont work.

Answer (score 3):

**What I was doing:**

```
    @Rule
    @JvmField
    var mActivityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(SplashScreenActivity::class.java)
```

Due to this rule, the **Espresso Library** was searching for the login `EditText` view on the `SplashScreenActivity`. The sad part was, this login `EditText` view was actually present in the `LoginActivity` as a result the test cases failed with the above-mentioned error.

**What I did to make everything work:**

```
    @Rule
    @JvmField
    var mActivityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(LoginActivity::class.java)
```

As soon as I changed the `Activity` from `SplashScreenActivity` to `LoginActivity` in the above rule. **Espresso** easily found this login `EditText` view and all the tests passed.

Just make sure you are pointing **Espresso** to the correct `Activity`/`Fragment` where the `View` is actually present.

Answer (score 0):

In case you try to access some view that wasn't showed you would see this error. For instance, you want to click some button but a whole screen wasn't showed.

Then you can simply use `try-catch` block around the action. It can be applied to `Kakao` library and, I think, `Espresso`,